# TelegramError: 409: Conflict: terminated by setWebhook request in Telegraf

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, telegram-bot

There is the following bot code:

```
export class TelegrafBot {
  private bot: Telegraf<Scenes.SceneContext>;
  private isInitialized: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.bot = new Telegraf(TELEGRAM_TOKEN);
  }

  initialize() {
    try {
      this.bot.telegram.setWebhook('URL');

      this.bot.launch();

      this.isInitialized = true;

      process.once('SIGINT', () => this.bot.stop('SIGINT'));
      process.once('SIGTERM', () => this.bot.stop('SIGTERM'));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  handleUpdate(body: Update, response: ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>) {
    if (!this.isInitialized) return;

    try {
      this.bot.handleUpdate(body, response);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}

export const telegrafBot = new TelegrafBot();
```

I deployed my bot on Heroku, but after some time it failed with the following error message:

```
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231966+00:00 app[web.1]: TelegramError: 409: Conflict: terminated by setWebhook request
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231969+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Telegram.callApi (/app/node_modules/telegraf/lib/core/network/client.js:293:19)
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231969+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231970+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async Polling.[Symbol.asyncIterator] (/app/node_modules/telegraf/lib/core/network/polling.js:30:33)
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231970+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async Polling.loop (/app/node_modules/telegraf/lib/core/network/polling.js:73:30)
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231971+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async Telegraf.launch (/app/node_modules/telegraf/lib/telegraf.js:189:13) {
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231972+00:00 app[web.1]:   response: {
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231972+00:00 app[web.1]:     ok: false,
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231972+00:00 app[web.1]:     error_code: 409,
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231972+00:00 app[web.1]:     description: 'Conflict: terminated by setWebhook request'
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231973+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231973+00:00 app[web.1]:   on: {
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231974+00:00 app[web.1]:     method: 'getUpdates',
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231974+00:00 app[web.1]:     payload: { timeout: 50, offset: 0, allowed_updates: [] }
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231975+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2022-12-25T06:21:25.231975+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I don't understand what it means and how I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from official Telegram API:

> Notes
>
> 1. You will not be able to receive updates using getUpdates for as long as an outgoing webhook is set up.
> 2. To use a self-signed certificate, you need to upload your public key certificate using certificate parameter. Please upload as InputFile, sending a String will not work.
> 3. Ports currently supported for webhooks: 443, 80, 88, 8443.

The cause in your case is point #1. To fix this, simply delete the webhook by leaving out the webhook URL:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook
```

So if your bot token is `479273:dnednbfdren`, it would look like the following:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot479273:dnednbfdren/setWebhook
```